# Confusion over a particular situation in which different variables have same name

Tags: java, scope

```
public class Arpan
{
  String arpan;

  public void arpan()
  {
    String arpan;
    arpan = "myname";
  }

  public void sen()
  {
    arpan = "myname";
  }
}
```

Why is there no problem during the execution of function arpan even if the String variables have the same name as arpan.

**Please explain in terms of how variables are created during execution of a program.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "shadowing."

Before we start, though, let's just use `arpan` for the two things in question, since having a method by that name (and using `Arpan` as the class name) gets confusing. :-) Let's refer to this code instead:

```
public class Foo
{
  String arpan;

  public void method1()
  {
    String arpan;
    arpan = "myname";
  }

  public void method2()
  {
    arpan = "myname";
  }
}
```

The `arpan` variable in `method1` is a local variable. Using the free symbol `arpan` within that method will refer to the variable, because the variable *shadows* the instance field.

Using the free symbol `arpan` inside `method2` will use the `arpan` instance field (it's not a "variable") declared in `Foo`, because it *isn't* shadowed by a local variable.

In general, think of it like this: The compiler looks for the symbol in the current scope and if not found, looks at the containing scope, and so on. More in [JLS §6.4.1: *Shadowing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).

---

Subjectively, I've always preferred to be explicit when referring to instance fields and methods by using `this.` in front of them, so that there's no ambiguity whether I'm referring to an instance field or a variable. Many tools can be configured to *require* that even though Java, the language, does not.

Comment: @ajb: Thanks!! Wow, I didn't know that, but I suppose I should have, Java keeps domains quite separate.

Answer (score 2):

Java lets you do this. The compiler knows from the context in which you use an identifier if it is a method name or a variable name. When you write `arpan = "myname"`, the compiler knows that you refer to a variable. When you write `arpan()`, the compiler knows that you refer to a method. The syntax is designed in such a way that the two contexts cannot be mistaken, i.e. there is no variable type that allows "straight" calling, and there is no variable to which a method name can be assigned directly.

Java also lets local variables "shadow" class-level variables with the same name. Note that you can always access a shadowed variable by using the `this.arpan` syntax.

The fact that you *can* do it does not mean that you *should* be doing it. Apart from some special cases, this leads to code that is harder to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

the variable declared in method is only available within that method. to reference the class level variable in that method you would need to use this.arpan.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem because your `arpan` defined in  `arpan()` is a local variable and its perfect valid in java to define local variable with same name as class variable, it is referred as [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)